# tkinter: How to have a treeview divided into sections with each section having different columns

Tags: dataframe, tkinter, treeview

I am currently working on adding data from a stored procedure into a dataframe and then outputting the dataframe to a treeview. The columns headers for each query that is run within the stored procedure are different and I have 4 queries running within the stored procedure. I was wondering if there is any way to have it so that once one of the queries data has been printed to the treeview, I can display the next query with its columns headers below the one that came before it. I have attached an image below to give an idea of what I am looking for. If there is a better approach to this I am open to new ideas since I am fairly new to tkinter.

[image]

Comment: Just use different treeviews.

Comment: @acw1668 is right. There really isn't a way to do this other than using multiple `Treeview` widgets. Wrapping them in a `Frame` should make seamless placement easier.